# Difference between != and =! with an example(in C++)

Tags: c++

What is the difference between the `!=` and `=!` operations in c++?

I tried googling for answer but it seems search engines don't take in some texts like `!=` or `=!`

Also I know what would be the logic of the difference but I can't think of a practical example for it. i mean let's say i have 2 parameters A and B on what condition A=!B would be true but A!=B would be false

```
if(A!=B) return true;
if(A=!B) return false;
```

I really couldn't find the answer from any search engine and it doesn't seems to be mentioned in any documentation.

Comment: != is a compare operator, =! is two operator, = and !. = is assgin operator,! negate operator

Comment: `A=!B` in an if statement is probably a typo and shouldn't be used in real code as it is confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This operation:

```
A!=B
```

determines if `A` is not equal to `B`.  If they're not equal, it evaluates to `true`.  If they are equal, it evaluates to `false`.  It's just a boolean comparison operation.

This operation:

```
A=!B
```

is *not* a boolean comparison.  It *sets* the value of `A` to the negated value of `B`.  (When used in this context it also *evaluates* to the new value of `A`, but isn't really a "comparison" in that regard.)  So if `B` is `true` then this will *set the value of `A`* to `false`.  It can be seen much more clearly as:

```
A = !B
```

The first operation only *compares*, it doesn't modify anything.  The second operation *modifies* `A`.

Comment: `A = !B` evalates to the new value of `A` (unless A has class type in which case it is an overloaded operator which may return anything)

Answer (score 2):

- `A!=B` means "`A` is not equal to `B`".
- `A=!B` means "Assign the complement of `B` to `A`, and yield the lvalue of `A`". It can (should) be rewritten to be `A = !B` or `A = (!B)`.